# I can't use history to redirect in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to redirect when an axios request is finished and everything has gone okey. But the problem is that I get de following error:
[image]

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import Sidebar from "../../User/Sidebar";
import NavBar from "../../User/NavBar";
import {
  Container,
  ContainerRequest,
  Text,
  Button,
  Alert,
  AlertContainer
} from "./NoTraineeAccountElements";
import ClassJWT from "../../../../classes/ClassJWT";
import axios from "axios";
import { serverPath } from "../../../../services/serverPath";
import { history }  from "../../../../services/history";

const NoTraineeAccount = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const upgrade = async () => {
    const JWT = new ClassJWT();
    const axiosReq = axios.create();
    await JWT.checkJWT();
    axiosReq
      .post(`${serverPath}/upgrade-to-trainer`, { token: JWT.getToken()})
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.statusCode === "200") history.push("/trainer");
        else setError(res.data.msg);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
      <NavBar toggle={toggle} />
      <Container>
        {error ? (
          <AlertContainer>
            <Alert className="alert alert-danger">{error}</Alert>
          </AlertContainer>
        ) : (
          <Fragment></Fragment>
        )}
        <ContainerRequest>
          <Text>{`Your account isn't a trainer account. Would you like to upgrade to a trainer account?`}</Text>
          <Button onClick={() => upgrade()}>
            <div className="btn btn-primary">Upgrade to Trainer Account</div>
          </Button>
        </ContainerRequest>
      </Container>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default NoTraineeAccount;
```

Maybe could be useful the services/history code, here it is:

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

I used history in other components and everything was okey, but I don't know why now is not working. If someone know how to fix it, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't about `history`.

The only code in your snippet that *could* yield that error is

```
<Alert className="alert alert-danger">{error}</Alert>
```

if `error` is an object with the keys named in the message in your screenshot. Using `JSON.stringify()` will sidestep this problem, so you can dig deeper into why something strange is being `setError`ed.

```
<Alert className="alert alert-danger">{JSON.stringify(error)}</Alert>
```

(ps. are you sure you should be looking at `res.data.statusCode`? Maybe `res.statusCode`? Are you sure it'd be a string `"200"`, not a number `200`?)